# Eliminating SQL clustered index seek nested in an optional outer apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustered-index

I'm running SQL Server 2008. I've built a large search query (contained in a user defined function) with many optional parameters. A simplified version of the result is something like:

```
Declare @optionalSubTableParameter as userDefinedTableType READONLY

select id
from table t

--here is optional parameter 1 (there are quite a few of these)
outer apply(
 select top (1) st.item
 from subTable st
 inner join @optionalSubTableParameter ostp
 on (ostp.value = st.item or ostp.value is null)
 where st.index = t.index 
 and ostp.value is not null
 -- also tried: (select top(1) * from @optionalSubTableParameter) is not null
)someParam

where (someParam.item is not null 
or (select top(1) * from @optionalSubTableParameter) is null)
```

So, the problem lies in the execution plan, I seem to be spending time on:

**clustered index seek (clustered)**

**[subTable].[IX_subTableIndex..**

**Cost:8%**

I know 8% isn't much, but this gets repeated 6 times (and soon to be a few more), so its already 48% of my execution time.

I thought by having the check of (@optionalSubTableParameter is not null) **within** the outer apply, I would avoid computations like the clustered index seek on an unneeded table (when there is no parameter specified). If anyone can help explain if there is a way for me to avoid this computation, that would be great!

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I can clarify anything (this is a grossly simplified version of the query that I'm actually running).

I apologize if there are any duplicate posts, but I had no luck finding an answer on my own.

Comment: bear in mind also that 8% of the **execution COST** is not necessarily 8% of the execution **TIME**.  Those could be using a lot of CPU cycles but processing instantly, unfortunately it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is only 8% of your execution cost.  If you have performance issues, keep looking because this won't be the fix.

Second, you are still doing the index seek because of this line:

`where st.index = t.index`

You MAY be able to eliminate it by switching the order of the `WHERE` clause in that outer apply but I wouldn't count on it.

Since it's an `AND` I think it may evaluate both components.  Someone else could probably address if that short circuits or not.

Comment: @JNK - I guess I assumed that since I have 6 of those optional parameters, the clustered index seek on the un-needed table is already 48% of my search query. I know I'm already getting a 24% hit from searching the @optionalParameter tables, but that is obviously un-avoidable.

Comment: @Brett - if you get 6 of those seeks then yes, it could be 48%.  If they are all null comparisons then it SHOULD be 48% of a very small cost.

Comment: @JNK - when I swapped the order in the WHERE clause, I didn't get that seek to disappear, I guess I thought that since it is ALWAYS false when the parameter was not used, it would evaluate that part of the where clause and leave the outer apply without using the st.index = t.index

Comment: @JNK - when you say if they are all null comparisons, the @parameter is null, but the subTable index is not null, the table scan on the @parameter is half the time of the seek on the subTable

Comment: @brett - you won't get much more optimized execution step than a clustered index seek.  It sounds like it's pretty optimal at this point.  You could potentially not use table valued parameters and use a temp table instead since you could index those.

Comment: @JNK-I'm passing the TVP's from .NET so was thinking it would be easier to just keep them that way, rather than storing them into temp tables, unless you think there would be a significant performance improvement?

Comment: @Brett - depends on the size of the TVP.  If it's more than a couple hundred thousand rows then indexes may help.

Comment: @JNK-its null most of the time, and if not, just a couple rows

Comment: @brett - then it won't matter at all.  Anything that small would likely ignore an index anyways.  Can you post the whole exec plan?  What kind of performance issues are you having exactly?

Comment: @JNK-actually I've been trying to work through the execution plan, but I'm still working on stripping things out so that its manageable to look at.. if I can get anything reasonable, I'll try to post the plan - thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: @brett - happy to help, a large part of my day is spent optimizing queries and I rather enjoy it :)

Comment: @JNK-I've been looking at the query a bit further, and as it turns out, the bottleneck is inserting the results of the 6 repetitions of this query into a temporary table. The temp table is later used to build a list of additional search filters, and the number of instances (counts) of each filter. The temp table is recalled a total of 20 times. Do you have any suggestions for improvement, or am I stuck since the temp table seems to be a necessity?

Comment: @brett - when you say `temp table` do you mean the Table-valued parameter?

Comment: @JNK- I'm using the results of a UDF(above) and storing into a temporary table (#table), for later recall. This table typically has upwards of 100k rows, so I assumed that #table would be a more applicable solution than @table, if I'm wrong, I would love to know!

Comment: For something that big it makes more sense to put it into a `#temptable`.  Are you sure the bottleneck is inserts?  There are a few thing you can do to speed up inserts, such as using `WITH (TABLOCK)` on the insert statement which under most circumstances will enable minimal logging.